# Is it possible to transfer token from other address if I have private key from it?

Tags: tokens, contract-invocation, private-key, fees, transferfrom

I know that if someone owns tokens he can simply call **transfer** method of contract to send money. I also know that for ERC20 contract owner of tokens can call **approve** for my account, and then I can call **transferFrom** to send his money. But I don't know if it's possible for me to transfer money from someone's account if I know his key without him calling **approve** before. In other words, is it possible to make transaction with **transfer** call to contract where transaction "from" field and "from" in a parameter to contract are different? I want to have the ability to make a lot of transactions from specific account to contract, such that they will transfer money from other accounts that I have keys to. It would be convinient, because in this case I can pay fee in eth only from one account and I don't need eth on all other accounts. With **approve/transferFrom** scheme I still need to call **approve** from all these accounts (and pay for fee) before every **transferFrom** which makes the whole idea useless.

If this helps, I want to interact with a specific token -- [USDT](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ERC20 token has two standard ways to make transfers as you said.

- transfer: need owner to all transfer.
- transferFrom: needs onwer to call approve.

In both cases the owner has to pay ether fees.

There are some proposals to create contracts that allow a third party to pay fees on behalf on someone else but USDT doesn't support it.